# How do I make a POST request to flask?

Tags: python, post, if-statement, get, flask

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to find a way to invoke the elif statement in the code below, without having to manually type in the url when I run my app. In other words, I'd like to be able to provide a url in one of my templates that will make a POST request for question(title). Can anyone give me insight?

```
@application.route('/question/<title>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def question(title):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        question = r.get(title+':question')
        return render_template('AnswerQuestion.html',
                           question = question)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        submittedAnswer = request.form['submittedAnswer'];

        answer=r.get(title+':answer')

        if submittedAnswer == answer:
            return render_template('Correct.html');
        else:
            return render_template('Incorrect.html',
                                   answer = answer,
                                   submittedAnswer = submittedAnswer);
```

Comment: You can't provide a URL that will trigger a POST request. You need to either submit a form (`<form ... action="POST">`) or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the`POST` request, you are getting the contents of a form. You can try to create a form whose `action="/question/some_title"` and `method="post"`. So on submit this will be handled on the`elif` part of your flask code. 
Or you can try sending am ajax request through JavaScript or jQuery, with relevant data, method and URL.

Comment: Could you give me an example of an ajax request that will include a URL that will lead to the elif part of my code?

Comment: Using jQuery: `$.ajax({  url: '/question/some_title', method:'post', data: 'someData you might want to pass'});` You might want to check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for a better understanding of how $.ajax works. OR `$.post( "/question/some_title", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});`

Comment: I'm new to jquery and JS, so I didn't really know how to implement your solution. I ended up directly providing a url like <a href="mysite.com/question/{{ title }}">Click this link.</a> Thank you very much for your help though!